# Loading content only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using a $_GET function to load content into the website,
what I want to do is add a Loading image into all that mess.
Right now it looks like it opens a whole new page.

Code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['page']) || isset($_POST['page'])) {
$page = trim(isset($_POST['page']) ? $_POST['page'] : $_GET['page']);
if (preg_match("/a-z/", $page)) {
    }
} else {
    $page = "index";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="navigation">
<ul class="nav-items">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/index.php?page=test">Test</a></li>
    <li><a href="/index.php?page=beta">Beta</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
<?
if ($page != '')
include('pages/'.$page . '.php');
else
{
include('pages/error.php');
}
?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, it works perfectly but I'd want it to show a Loading... image while loading the content , and instead of reloading whole page would be great to load the content div ONLY.

I did not try javascript solution since I didn't find anything that would work correctly and would keep the links working *(for example http://example.com/index.php?page=test with already loaded the text.php file from pages folder)*. Plus I'm a real newbie in javascript so I have no idea what to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is opening a whole new page because it is. Your only option would be javascript. If I were wanting to do this, I would always only load the index page with nothing in your content div except the loading icon. Then once the page is loaded have jquery read the  get variable and make an ajax request for the content of the page and load it into the div.

```
<div id="content">
    <div id='page'></div>
</div>
```

Then, to make it easier on you since you are unfamiliar with javascript I would include the following jquery plugin: https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl

then in .js file:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var loading_annimation = "<div class='loading'></div>";
    var page = $.url().param("page");
    if(page){
        $('#page').load(loading_annimation ).load('/special_php_file_that_includes_JUST_content.php?page='+page);
    } else {
        $('#page').load(loading_annimation ).load('/special_php_file_that_includes_JUST_content.php?page=index');
    }

    $(document).on('click','.link', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).attr("data-link");
        $('#page').load(loading_annimation ).load('/special_php_file_that_includes_JUST_content.php?page='+page);
    });
});
```

Then you will need to change your links to do something like this:

```
<a class='link' data-link='beta' href="/index.php?page=beta">Beta</a>
```

Comment: You then could also in the click() function rewrite the URL to include the correct ?page=beta link too, but that is up to you. How it stands now (without any checking for typos) it should work if someone navigates to /index.php?page=beta or right clicks the link and opens in new tab, or just navigates to the page and clicks the link

Comment: and the special_php...
`<?php
if (isset($_GET['page']) || isset($_POST['page'])) {
$page = trim(isset($_POST['page']) ? $_POST['page'] : $_GET['page']);
if (preg_match("/a-z/", $page)) {
    }
} else {
    $page = "index";
}
if ($page != '')
include('pages/'.$page . '.php');
else
{
include('pages/error.php');
}
?>` ?

Comment: Yeah either include the page or error page. Ideally you could navigate to special_php_file_that_includes_JUST_content.php?page=beta and it should return just the portion of the html that goes in your content div. And that is what loads into the div

Comment: Okay finaly its working, now there's another problem , The links work perfectly don't get me wrong. But while pressing the menu buttons the link in browser doesn't change. Any ideas? for example , you are on http://example.com/index.php , pressing buttons ( for example u press on Beta button ) it loads the Beta content but the link in browser stays http://example.com/index.php , without the ?page=Beta . Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: If you are OK with only supporting modern browsers ( http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate ) then you can easily put this in the on click function: `window.history.pushState(null, null, '/index.php?page='+page);`

Comment: Thanks, in case it will have some problems with older browser, is there any solution ?

Comment: Yes there is another plugin that has some popularity, https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/ but I have not used it before.

Comment: Another small thing, is there way adding some sort of interval on page loads ? Currently i don't see the Loading at all since the browser loads everything really fast , i'd like it to load pages within like 1-2 seconds for example , just to make sure that the js will show the loading div

Comment: You can add .delay(500) between the two .load()s which will delay the next action for half a second (500 milliseconds)

Comment: Actually I think I am wrong, I think .load() ignores the .delay().
 Look into the setTimeout() function. You would then split it into two parts: `$('#page').load(loading_annimation);` and then settimeout for however long, and inside the timeout function use `$('#page').load('/special_php_file_that_includes_JUST_content.php?page='+page);` or whatever. Here are some examples of that function. I would go with the first: http://www.sitepoint.com/settimeout-example/

Answer (score 2):

The only solution to this problem is with JavaScript because PHP will only execute on the server and will only present HTML on the client side.

If you understand the HTTP request/response system, you will know that a request is sent to the server and then the server responds back with the page content, which will be the HTML (and CSS and any client-side scripts such as JavaScript). This method normally means having to reload the page but if you use AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML), this acts as a layer between the client and the server, allowing the user to request content without having to reload the page.

The most simple way of doing this is with jQuery. Be sure to include the jQuery library and put your code inside the `$(document).ready();` function so that it executes when the page has finished loading.

Fortunately, this particular task is fairly simple, although it will require restructuring your website/application slightly. You will need to have the content `echo`ed or `print`ed onto a different page with PHP.

On your main page that will be used and seen by the users, you would simply write `$("#container").load("page.html");` where `container` is the id of the container you want to load the content into.

If you want different content to be loaded with different buttons, you could do this (as long as you give your links the correct `id`s:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#alpha").onclick(function() {
        $("#container").load('page.html?page=alpha');
    });

    $("#beta").onclick(function() {
        $("#container").load('page.html?page=beta');
    });
});
```

**Edit:** I'm so sorry, I missed out the important part about the loading image, but the other answer demonstrates this well, so there is no point in repeating it.

Comment: is there any way doing it with javascript and saving the links ? for example if someone has a link for a page Downloads ( http://example.com/index.php#downloads ) would it load the downloads page or will just give an error?

Comment: You can get the anchor name/hash with `var hash = location.hash.replace("#","");` And then you could set that as the variable after `?=` in the URL when you are `load`ing a new page into the container. You could have the PHP script generate the relevant content. Alternatively, you could have the PHP file generate  all of the content you need (or just type it into a HTML yourself) as long as each section is in a container with its own `id`, so that you could add the hash from this page after `page.html` to load the content from the container on the other page with the same name.

Comment: As an example, if the URL was `example.com/index.php#downloads'`, then you would write `$("#container").load("page.html#" + hash);`

Comment: Where do I set file locations though ? 
Files located in pages folder.

Comment: If you mean you have several pages in a file called 'pages' then you would write `$("#container").load("pages/alpha.html");` or, a more general example as I mentioned above, `$("#container").load("pages/" + hash + ".html");`

Comment: Ugh been trying doing it all, but without php it doesn't want to work at all.